# Essential Perl utility modules?

Tags: perl, refactoring, cpan

I'm currently cleaning up an older Perl project. Large parts of it were written by myself some time ago when I barely knew Perl. I did probably reinvent the wheel several times.

Now is the time where I want to throw out any duplicated code and, if possible, replace everything which is already available in high-quality CPAN modules by those.

**Which essential Perl utility modules do you know of that every Perl developer should be aware of?**

This question is similar to the question [Useful Perl modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101719/useful-perl-modules), however I'm not concered about the *big* modules listed there (e.g. DBI, Template, et. al.).

Comment: Voting to close as [non constructive](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#link-close) - it's a poll, not a question

Comment: Well, I'm looking for advice. I thought that's what this site is all about.

Comment: Wasn't there some kind of Perl-plus-key-modules distribution, called iPerl or uPerl or Perli or something? It included a set of useful modules for database handling etc., to make it more like PHP with everything built in. That list of modules might make a good answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use these ones a lot:

[Path::Class](http://p3rl.org/Path%3a%3aClass) for directory and file paths manipulation

[Class::Load](http://p3rl.org/Class%3a%3aLoad) ( for loading classes at runtime )

[Try::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Try%3a%3aTiny) ( for easy, and correct exception handling )

[FindBin::libs](http://p3rl.org/FindBin%3a%3alibs) etc.,

[Email::Valid](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aValid) for e-mail address validation

also, [Regexp::Common](http://p3rl.org/Regexp%3a%3aCommon) for common regexes.

Answer (score 1):

I use the `::Util` modules regularly (including [List::MoreUtils](http://p3rl.org/List%3a%3aMoreUtils) which isn't core). Especially the `reduce` and `first` functions from [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List%3a%3aUtil).

One other that I use constantly is [File::chdir](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3achdir). It provides access to the working directory via tied variables. This allows localizeable changes to the working directory per block. I like its interface so much that I even wrote [Tie::Select](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aSelect) which provides a similar interface to the `select` function.

tjmc correctly suggests [Try::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Try%3a%3aTiny), which reminds me of [Capture::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Capture%3a%3aTiny). This module captures the output of nearly anything, including Perl commands, system calls and XS modules.

Comment: You should consider using [File::pushd](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::pushd) instead of File::chdir.  I understand there are some edge-cases with localizing the tied variables that chdir uses.  pushd uses a normal object with a destructor, which makes it more reliable.

Comment: @cjm, can you either elaborate or find some doc on this? It is interesting to me, both personally and for the modules I write. I would personally prefer the stack that local provides rather than depend on destructors.

Comment: I should say, my reasoning is that these tied vars are necessarily singletons, where the objects aren't fully. In sufficiently pathological cases the order of destructors can matter and this order is not well defined.

Comment: David Golden, the author of File::pushd (and current maintainer of File::chdir), said in IRC "File::chdir can fail to unchdir if scope is exited via exceptions.  File::pushd works through object destruction, which is more reliable." Re: order of destruction, you should have only 1 pushd object in any given scope, so the order of destruction should be well defined.

Comment: Hmmm, that is an interesting problem, and worrisome. My only other concern is that File::pushd is far less powerful. I guess I will have to weigh these concerns going forward. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Perl::Tidy and Perl::Critic, not for the modules themselves but for the two scripts, perltidy and perlcritic. With these two, tackling a big project is much, much easier.